# How to for-loop output in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, output

The output itself is working but how can i format the output or write it to a variable or array using outside the for loop ?

```
...
for item in soup.findAll('span', {"itemprop":"actor"}):
    print item.text
...
```

Output example:

```
Sylvester Stallone
Arnold Schwarzenegger
```

But Output should look something like:

```
Actors: Sylvester Stallone, Arnold Schwarzenegger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is this...

```
actors = [item.text for item in soup.findAll('span', {"itemprop":"actor"})]
print "Actors: %s" % (", ".join(actors))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
actor_list = soup.findAll('span', {"itemprop":"actor"})
print "Actors: {0}".format(", ".join(actor_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without save it to a variable:

```
print "Actors: ",
...
for item in soup.findAll('span', {"itemprop":"actor"}):
    print item.text, ",",
...
```